# How to programmatically delete a deep directory hierarchy on windows?

Tags: c#, windows

I have code that temporarily creates a fairly deep hierarchy of files and directories.  In C# (.Net Framework 4.7.2), I'm using the DirectoryInfo class to store the root of the tree.  Calling root.Delete(true) ends up throwing a DirectoryNotFoundException.  Oddly: the path in the exception is for a file, not a directory.

The root path is 112 characters.  The total path (i.e. including the root) length for the file in the exception is 264 characters.

I'm fairly confident this is a symptom of windows path length issues because if I set root to a shallower location, the delete will succeed.

I can delete the root folder (at the deep location) using the windows browser, so there is clearly some way to accomplish my goal.  Ideas of where to look?

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison#limits

Comment: Use recursion to get a list of subfolders and then delete them including their contents.

Comment: Yep, the .Net version matters: if <= 4.6.1, you'll have troubles with paths longer than 260 chars: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=net-7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Using .net 4.7.2 -- edited the question to add.